# Will not POST with a USB mouse or keyboard plugged in

Tags: usb, bios

I have an Abit KN9 motherboard, and a USB keyboard and mouse. The computer will not POST with the keyboard or mouse plugged in, but they can be used (and they are fully functional) if you plug them in later, after POST. On the POST side of things, it hangs when it shows the installed processor, and goes no further - pressing DEL to go to setup will not work. I've tried disabling legacy USB support as recommended, but can't find the option anywhere in the BIOS.

Comment: have you tried resetting the BIOS to default values?

Comment: @Xantec, I tried both failsafe defaults and optimisied defaults, to no avail.

Comment: If you can disable booting from a usb device in the bios. Update the bios to the latest version.

Comment: @Moab, do you know how to update the BIOS from Ubuntu (or do I have to have Windows installed?) Also, is it possible to screw up the BIOS by updating it incorrectly? My motherboard is not dual BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to perform a BIOS update which fixed the problem.

More on MajorGeeks: http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=229762.